# Xamarin Android & AIDL: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Bad magic number for Bundle

Tags: android, xamarin, aidl

I am using an Xamarin Android to connect with a Android service. After I auto-generate the stubs for the .aidl files and run the project I encounter the following error.

"Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'Bad magic number for Bundle"

[image]

I am using a Parceable class that holds two float values.

```
public class TLGeoPoint : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelable
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }

    public TLGeoPoint()
    {

    }

    public TLGeoPoint(Parcel parcel)
    {
        ReadFromParcel(parcel);
    }

    [ExportField("CREATOR")] // Need a reference to Mono.Android.Export
    public static TLGeoPointCreator InitializeCreator()
    {
        return new TLGeoPointCreator();
    }

    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, [GeneratedEnum] ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        dest.WriteFloat(lat);
        dest.WriteFloat(lng);
    }

    public void ReadFromParcel(Parcel parcel)
    {
        lat = parcel.ReadFloat();
        lng = parcel.ReadFloat();
    }
}

public class TLGeoPointCreator : Java.Lang.Object, IParcelableCreator
{
    public Java.Lang.Object CreateFromParcel(Parcel source)
    {
        TLGeoPoint objGeo = new TLGeoPoint();
        objGeo.lat = source.ReadFloat();
        objGeo.lng = source.ReadFloat();
        return objGeo;
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object[] NewArray(int size)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.Object[size];
    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a bug in the Xamarin AIDL code generation that is causing the Bag Magic Number exception or it something that I am missing to add.

Please note that the service accepts a callback function and sends data through that callback. I receive this error before the callback is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in Xamarin AIDL generator.

In meantime, until the bug is resolved on Xamarin side, you have several options.

1. Remove generated AIDL interface, remove your *.aidl files, write IPC marshalling code by hand. Ough.
2. Use Messenger + Bundle as described in [this official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger). There will be a bit of boilerplate for each method, but this approach is usable overall.
3. Alternatively move the IPC code to separate Java library module. If you do so, you should be able to generate your IPC proxy implementation using official *aidl* tool or by other means (such using a [library](https://github.com/chdir/aidl2) I wrote myself for that purpose).

Comment: I guess this was reported in another Stackoverflow post a few years back. I dont think Microsoft has worked on fixing this.